# Stream lookup in PENTAHO Data Integration

Tags: pentaho, kettle

Is it possible to get multiple result rows after evaluating a stream lookup step in Pentaho Data integration ? I have been trying this thing using a excel input file. But the result set always contains one row. Actually there are more rows to be displayed as result. Please help

Comment: Do you mean your stream lookup step only produces one row total, or that it only produces one output row for each input row?

Comment: 6 rows are added as input and 3 rows must be output. But in this case only one row is given as output

Comment: You get rows from your Excel file based on keys that flow through the Stream Lookup step. Where do the keys come from? Another Excel file?

Comment: its from previous transformation. using get rows and select values

Comment: Then I believe @Codek's answer is the best approach. You can use another `Select Values` after the `Merge Join` to remove columns you don't want, or just don't use them.

Answer (score 2):

You want to do a join not a lookup of a single value. So if for the current row the lookup matches 2 values you want 2 rows right?  So use the merge join step instead. You'll need the incoming rows in both streams sorted on the key which can be a pain if you're processing huge amounts of data but thats the way to do it.

Comment: Actually I dont want to join the rows. I just want to scan the contents of an excel file using stream lookup control using a key column and want to return the rows  matching the key column. Total there are 6 rows with 6 columns. The key column used is string format.

Comment: you want to return more than 1 row for a given key or not?

Comment: Yes. I want to fetch more than one row (which is the actual result)